# two way communication using two unidirectional pipes

Tags: c, unix, pipe, ipc

Hi have written a code so that a parent sends a message through a pipe, the child receives it and print it to screen ... then the child should reply back an and the parent prints the msg inside the pipe .. the code worked perfectly with communication from parent to child  .. but when it comes to the opposite close() return errors and the message is not passed ... note that I use also a shared memory to make some synchronization and control..I know there is a special type of pipes between children and parents ..but I want to use the general case one if it works for that purpose and please tell me if that is true .. here is the code

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sched.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
////creating shared memory with check///
int  shmid ;
int err;
char *shm;
shmid = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE,3 ,IPC_CREAT | IPC_EXCL | 0666 );
shm=shmat(shmid,0, IPC_CREAT | IPC_EXCL | 0666  );
if (shmid > -1)
{
printf("shared memory created succefully\n");
shm[0]='C';
shm[1]='C';
shm[2]='C';
}
else
{
return 0;
}


/////////////////////////////////////////

//////////making pipe with check/////////
int  testpipe[2];
int  size_ptr ;
char buff1[51];
char buff2[51];
char buff3[51];
char buff4[51];
int check;
check = pipe(testpipe);
if (check > -1)
{
printf("pipe created succefully\n");
}
else
{
return 0 ;
}
////////////////////////////////////////


///////////making new process///////////
pid_t pid ;
pid = fork();
////////////////////////////////////////


///////////Executing process ///////////
    if (pid > 0) //am in parent
    {


//////////partA////////////////////
     strcpy(buff1,"Hi am tweeting now ..\n");
    // err = close(testpipe[0]);
     printf("... Close state %d \n",err);
     write(testpipe[1],buff1,25);
     close(testpipe[1]);
     printf("partA Ended ... Close state %d \n");

/////////////////////////////////////
shm[0] = 'O'; // lock 2 is opened here

shm[1] = 'C'; // lock 1 is closed
while(shm[1] != 'O');
/////////////////////////////////////

//////////partD///////////////////
    //close(testpipe[1]);
    err = read(testpipe[0],buff4,25);
    //close(testpipe[1]);
    printf(" error state%i \n",err);
    printf("the output is : %s\n",buff4);
    printf("part D Ended ...\n");
    printf("Close state %d ... %i \n",err,EACCES);
    shmdt(shm);
    return 0;

    }
    else if (pid ==0) // am in child now
    {
    while(shm[0]!= 'O');  //from child read'

    ///////////////////////////////////

    //////////partb////////////////////
    read(testpipe[0],buff2,25);
    //err = close(testpipe[0]);
    printf("Close state %d \n",err);
    printf("the output is : %s\n",buff2);
    printf("partB Ended ... Close state %d\n",err);
    //close(testpipe[0]);
    //////////////////////////////////

    ///////////////    /part c////////////
     close(testpipe[0]);
     err = write(testpipe[1],buff3,25);
     printf("III... Close state %d \n",err);
     err = close(testpipe[1]);
     printf("Close state %d \n",err);
     printf("partC Ended ..\n");
     shm[1] ='O';
/////////////////////////////////////////////////
     //shm[1] = 'O';
     shm[0] = 'C';
     while(shm[0]!= 'O');
     printf("process child closed\n");

    }
    else{
     printf("Error Ocuured");
    }
//////////////////////////////////////////



}
```

Edit : I changed the title
[a screen shot of the terminal output here :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFVmp.png)

Comment: Pipes are unidirectional. It gets messy if both parent and child write and read on a single pipe. Use two pipes. Make sure you close enough file descriptors.

Comment: I am trying to make a two pipes approach ... I'll post here if that's not going to work...thanks for your rapid comment :)

Answer (score 2):

> Hi have written a code so that a parent sends a message through a
>   pipe, the child receives it and print it to screen ... then the child
>   should reply back an and the parent prints the msg inside the pipe ..
>   the code worked perfectly with communication from parent to child ..
>   but when it comes to the opposite close() return errors and the
>   message is not passed ...

Your code prints messages about the `close()`s, but as your code presently stands, those messages for the most part do not report the actual return values of your `close()` calls.  You have a variety of errors revolving around them.

But how do you know that the message is not passed?  You write to the pipe from `buff3`, which is never initialized or written to.  How, then, would your recognize whether the message was passed?  If you're *lucky* then you pass a message whose first byte is `'\0'`, so that when you print, it serves as an empty string.

> note that I use also a shared memory to make
>   some synchronization and control..

No, you don't.  One *can* use shared memory to host synchronization objects such as process-shared semaphores and mutexes, but shared memory does not by itself provide any synchronization semantics.  As such, your program contains data races, and its behavior is therefore undefined.

I would recommend semaphores for the kind of locking you seem to be performing, except that it does not appear to be necessary in the first place.  Appropriate pipe usage does not require additional synchronization.

"Appropriate" in this case would be to use a different pipe for each communication direction.  Although it would be possible to use just one for both directions, doing so is messy and unnecessary.

> I know there is a special type of
>   pipes between children and parents

There is no special type of pipe between parent and child processes.

Processes normally obtain access to a pipe created via the `pipe()` function either by calling `pipe()` themselves or by inheriting one or more open pipe-end file descriptors from their parent process.  When obtaining access this way, only processes with a common ancestor can communicate with each other via pipes.  Although communication between parent and child processes is a common example, such pipes are in no way constrained to that specific usage pattern.

---

Overall:

- My primary recommendation is to ditch the shared memory and non-working "locks", and instead use two pipes, one for each direction.
- If you must use only one pipe, then perform proper synchronization.  For your apparent purposes, it looks like it would be sufficient to use one or two semaphores -- process-shared and residing in shared memory -- to control which process is permitted to read from the pipe at any given time.  There are other alternative, too, but shared memory alone does not provide what you need for that.

Comment: I am trying to do so now .. but facing a problem .. which is how could the parent know the descriptors created by the child ... as i understand (and correct if that's not correct) that the process which call pipe() is that process that have write permission ow i 'll face segmentation faults ..thnx

Comment: @AbdAllahTalaat, the parent does not know the descriptors created by the child.  If you're going to use two pipes then the parent must create both of them.

Comment: And written with linguistic flare -- that's a bonus.

Comment: Wow ... Yes Guys ... it worked the other way too ... i'll write an answer with the code and screen shots thanks for all of you ...

Answer (score 0):

and sync the process operation (r/w) using a shared memory .. it worked ..

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sched.h>
#include <string.h>

#define parent_read parent_child[0]
#define parent_write parent_child[1]
#define child_read child_parent[0]
#define child_write child_parent[1]

int main()
{
////creating shared memory with check///
int  shmid ;
int err;
char *shm;
shmid = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE,4 ,IPC_CREAT | IPC_EXCL | 0666 );
shm=shmat(shmid,0, IPC_CREAT | IPC_EXCL | 0666  );
if (shmid > -1)
{
printf("shared memory created succefully\n");
shm[0]='I';
shm[1]='I';

}
else
{
return 0;
}


/////////////////////////////////////////

//////////making pipe with check/////////
int  parent_child[2];
int  child_parent[2];
int  size_ptr ;
char buff1[51];
char buff2[51];
char buff3[51];
char buff4[51];
int check1;
int check2;
check1 = pipe(parent_child);
check2 = pipe(child_parent);
if (check1 > -1 && check2 > -1)
{
printf("pipe 1 created succefully\n");
}
else
{
return 0 ;
}
////////////////////////////////////////


///////////making new process///////////
pid_t pid ;
pid = fork();
////////////////////////////////////////


///////////Executing process ///////////






    if (pid > 0) //am in parent
    {


//////////partA////////////////////
     strcpy(buff1,"Hi am tweeting now ..\n");
     close(parent_read);
     printf("... Close state %d \n",err);
     write(parent_write,buff1,25);
     close(parent_write);
     printf("partA Ended ... Close state %d \n");


/////////////////////////////////////
    shm[1] = 'B';
    shm[0]='A';
    while(shm[0] == 'A');
//////////partD///////////////////



    close(child_write);
    printf(" error state%i \n",err);
    read(child_read,buff4,25);
    close(child_read);
    printf("from child  : %s\n",buff4);
    printf("part D Ended ...\n");
    shmdt(shm);
    return 0;

    }








    else if (pid ==0) // am in child now
    {

    while(shm[1] == 'I');
    //////////partb////////////////////
    close(parent_write);
    read(parent_read,buff2,25);
    close(parent_read);
    printf("Close state %d \n",err);
    printf("from parent : %s\n",buff2);
    printf("partB Ended ... Close state %d\n",err);
    //close(testpipe[0]);
    //////////////////////////////////

    ///////////////    /part c////////////
     close(child_read);
     strcpy(buff3,"Hello from the other side...");
     err = write(child_write,buff3,25);
     printf("III... Close state %d \n",err);
     err = close(child_write);
     printf("Close state %d \n",err);
     printf("partC Ended ..\n");
     printf("process child closed\n");
     shm[0]='D';
    }
    else{
     printf("Error Ocuured");
    }
//////////////////////////////////////////



}
```

parent to child : the tweety comment
child to parent : hello from the other side

screen shot : [the output on terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0gV9.png)